Pyspark dataframe ERROR: column "DateCreated" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type character varying
Thru Pyspark dataframe, Records are selected(thru spark.read.format) from SQL Server & insert into Postgres table using dataframe.write option. During the insert, it is throwing with following error.
Batch entry 0
INSERT INTO test ("Num","DateCreated","DateLastModified","RecordType","RecordSubType","coName","RunDateTime","RunIdent","Payer","ProcessYear","etlInsertId","etlUpdateId") VALUES (1,'2019-06-18 19:45:36.8716624 -06:00','2019-06-18 19:45:36.8716624 -06:00','H',' ','DataBricks','202106181943','CONSUMER','111023',2022,0,0`) was aborted: ERROR: column "DateCreated"


is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type character varying

And "DateCreated" is TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE (data type) in Postgres table.
0
Following is the write option
dataframe.write
.format(jdbc)
.option(url, url)
.option(driver, org.postgresql.Driver)
.option(dbtable, f{table_name})
.option(user, username)
.option(password, password)
.option(ssl, True)
.option(sslmode, require)
.mode('append')
.save()
And the error is as follows
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o142.save. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 8 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 8.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 36) (10.86.5.238 executor 8): java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO sandbox.HeaderRecord_test ("Id","DateCreated","DateLastModified","RecordType","RecordSubType","TransmitterName", "BatchDateTime","BatchIdent","TransmitterEfin","FilingYear","etlInsertId","etlUpdateId") VALUES (1,'2019-06-18 19:45:36.8716624 -06:00','2019-06-18 19:45:36.8716624 -06:00','H',' ','TaxAct ', '202106181943','CONSUMER','111023',2022,0,0) was aborted: ERROR: column "DateCreated" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. Position: 225 Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch. at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:169)
Let me know what error am I making here?
Thanks in advance.
I am expecting records to be inserted into Postgres table.
